# Speech component works fine while debugging but throws error when installed application is run

Tags: c#, installation, speech-recognition

I am working on C# (.Net 3.5) desktop application, trying to build speech recognition in it. I am using Microsoft speech for implementing speech recognition. I have taken reference of Microsoft.Speech and installed following:

1. Microsoft Speech Platform SDK 11.0 - Both 32 and 64 bit
2. Microsoft Speech Runtime - Both 32 and 64 bit
3. Microsoft Speech Recognition Language TELE (en-US)

I have an installer project which creates .msi file of the application by which application can be installed. When I run my application in debug mode it works fine but when I run installed application on the same computer, it throws below exception:

```
No recognizer of the required ID found. Parameter name: culture
```

I have used below code

```
Dim cultureInfo As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US") 
Dim _recognizer As New SpeechRecognitionEngine(cultureInfo)
```

I receive exception at second line. I am using VS 2010 with Windows 8.

Comment: Any more information?

Comment: You get an error or an exception? , by the way, add your new information to your question and format them properly. 
place any needed snippets of code, specially the ones that relate to your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have added related information in the question itself.